# How to prevent mobile view in c# web browser?

Tags: c#

I have created a web browser using `c#` browser control. All websites works fine but when i try to navigate to Facebook, it says, "You're using a browser that isn't supported by Facebook, so we've redirected you to a simpler version to give you the best experience." I have included a screenshot[image].

I want to navigate all the websites in desktop version. I want to stop the mobile view forever. What can i do?

Comment: I am using `WinForms`. How can I define a user agent in my http header? To be honest I don't know what a http header is.

Comment: As a browser, you just display whatever the server returns. Most likely it's an issue with Facebook specifically, that only shows the full site with specific browsers and a bare-bones version for everything else. Impresonating a "supported" browser though the user agent could help.

Comment: @Alejando, How can I do that?

Comment: I have used as you said but it still goes to mobile view. This is what I have tried, `getCurrentBrowser().Navigate(AddressBar.Text, null, null, "User-Agent: WebKit, Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)")`